# Is their any mechanism in Docker Content Trust to ensure only image signed by me are pulled not signed by anyone?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, azure-devops, cloud, devops

I want to make sure the images that will be pulled in order to deploy are only signed by me. By default Docker Content Trust allows signed images pulling regardless of being signed by anyone.

Comment: Azure provides the feature to enable content trust for repository. Does this is also associated with azure. My primary goal is to allow this using azure.